# How can i reduce __TEXT segment size in iOS App?

Tags: ios, xcode, text, size, segment

My App failed to submit due to app size problem before, and the following build options were applied.
So I could submit an app.

*. Dead Code Stripping(DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING) : YES
*. Enable C++ Exceptions(GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS) : NO

But at this time, I can not submit my App architecture because of the following issue in arm64 architecture.

**ERROR ITMS-90122 : "Invalid ExecutableSize. The size of your app`s executable file '******' is 60948500 bytes for architecture 'arm64', which exceeds the maximum allowed size of 60MB."**

Exactly, the size of the '__TEXT,__text' section`s size is overflow.
Is there a way to solve this problem while keeping  Deployment Target(8.0)?

---

[My App Build Settings]

iOS Deployment Target : 8.0
Devices : Universal
Validate Architecture : arm64 armv7 arm7s
Build Active Architecture Only : NO

Strip Debug Symbols During Copy : YES
Strip Linked Product : YES
Strip Style : All Symbols

DeadCode Stripping : YES
Optimization Level : Fastest, smallest(-Os)
Enable C++ Exceptions : NO

---

Answer (score 0):

1.reduce template usage. 
2.convert some data code in _TEXT to _DATA by remove const and static.
3.move template class shared data to base class.